# Combine multiple textarea inputs into one textarea and make it editable with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery code that combine multiple user textarea inputs into one textarea, but the last is not editable. How to acquire this (without buttons or any supplementary clicks)?

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", function () {
    var form = $('.combine').not('#Voltes5');
    var vals = form.map(function () {
        var value = $.trim(this.value)
        return value ? value : undefined;
    }).get();
    $('#Voltes5').val(vals.join(', '))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="combine" id="input1"></textarea>
<textarea class="combine" id="input2"></textarea>
<textarea class="combine" id="Voltes5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it was happening was because the event was bind with `document`. So, whenever events like `change` or `keyup` were taking place, the text inside first two `textareas` was getting added to the third one (even if these events were taking place for third `textarea`).

To resolve it, I have added this code. The event is bind with `document`. However, changes will take place only when those event will happen for first two `textareas`. My selector is a lil different, but will help in case you have many textareas. :)

**NOTE :** This code will let you type inside the third `textarea`, but in case you type inside first two `textareas`, the text you typed inside third one will get lost.

```js
var selector = '.combine[id^=input]';

$(document).on("change keyup", selector, function() {
  var vals = $(selector).map(function() {
    var value = $.trim(this.value)
    return value ? value : undefined;
  }).get();
  $('#Voltes5').val(vals.join(', '))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="combine" id="input1"></textarea>
<textarea class="combine" id="input2"></textarea>
<textarea class="combine" id="Voltes5"></textarea>
```

Comment: One question: the `var selector = '.combine[id^=input]';` is linked to `textarea` ids? My real  textareas doesn't have the same word like "input" in their ids (but, sure, I can arrange this). Is this a problem?

Comment: Yes, this selection is based on the id. In case you don't have similar id's, you can try different selector. `$('.combine').not('#Voltes5');` is fine too :)